# Deploy spring boot war to tomcat failed - 404 error

Tags: spring, tomcat

I deployed a spring boot war to tomcat server, i get a 404 error and didn't see any tomcat logs when I tried to access it.
I've changed Context path on server.xml
[image: HTTP Status 404]

Also, it doesn't seem like the spring project is running.
Are there any suggestions to fix it?

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = '-'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.0'
    
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect
    implementation group: 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-layout-dialect', version: '3.1.0'

}


bootWar{
    archiveName("ROOT.war")
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

MyApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

ServletInitializer.java

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

}
```

tomcat log

```
20-Jun-2022 12:17:03.944 INFO [Thread-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:03.968 INFO [Thread-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:04.045 INFO [Thread-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:04.052 INFO [Thread-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.268 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setPath A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.343 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.31 (Ubuntu)
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 16 2022 18:51:24 UTC
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.31.0
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.346 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.347 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.4.0-1018-aws
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.348 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.348 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.351 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.15+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.352 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Private Build
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.352 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /var/lib/tomcat9
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.353 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat9
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.355 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.356 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.357 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.362 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.364 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.364 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat9
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat9
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.367 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.6.5].
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.367 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.368 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:05.375 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:06.084 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:06.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1,471] milliseconds
20-Jun-2022 12:17:06.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:06.315 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31 (Ubuntu)]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:12.419 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
20-Jun-2022 12:17:12.640 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:12.648 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/host-manager] in deployment descriptor [/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml] has been ignored
20-Jun-2022 12:17:13.716 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
20-Jun-2022 12:17:13.721 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml] has finished in [1,081] ms
20-Jun-2022 12:17:13.723 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:13.724 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/manager] in deployment descriptor [/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml] has been ignored
20-Jun-2022 12:17:14.651 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
20-Jun-2022 12:17:14.694 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml] has finished in [971] ms
20-Jun-2022 12:17:14.700 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
20-Jun-2022 12:17:14.732 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [8,574] milliseconds
```

server.xml

```
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context docBase="ROOT" path="/" reloadable="false" />
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
```

Comment: Please check [ask] and edit your question to be more precise on _"is not working and can't access URLs"_: The logs don't show errors, and you might want to provide a full [mcve] (including the actual URLs and errors observed).

Comment: sorry for it. My English is not good. Whenever I tried to access {server_ip}/, i got 404 error.

Type Status Report

Message /

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.